# How to create a Dropdown with input option

Tags: angular

I want to create a Dropdown with input option when i select "other" option from the dropdown list.Below i'll share my dropdown list.
[image: dropdown list]

And here is my html section. Here i want to convert this dropdown to input field when i select "Other(Please specify option)". Is there any possibility to achieve it

```
<div class="col-sm-4 require">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
          <mat-select autofocus placeholder="What cultural background or ethnicity do you identify with?" formControlName="otherCulturalBackgroundID"
            [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && formControls.otherCulturalBackgroundID.errors }" required>
            <mat-option *ngFor="let race of masterRace" [value]="race.id">
              {{race.value}}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-select>
          <mat-error *ngIf="formControls.otherCulturalBackgroundID.errors">
            Please select other cultural background
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best way for do this is looking for autocomplete
https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples

In alternative, you can make an input field in case selected option is other. Firs add an ngModel to selected element

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
    <option> 
        //your option
    </option>
</select>
```

```
<div *ngIf="selectedOption === 'other' "> //here, in 'other' you have to insert the value you decide to store as selected
    <input />
</div>
```

See docs for ngModel https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: My question is different